# RecyclerView CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, adapter, recyclerview

*Знаю, что эта тема много раз поднималась для `ListView`, но ни как не могу разобраться с ней на примере `RecyclerView`.*

Есть `RecyclerView`, в котором повторяются `CardView`. `RecyclerView` заполняется адаптером. Когда отмечаю несколько чек-боксов, при скроллинге вниз, некоторые чек-боксы сами становятся отмеченными. Понял, что нужно описать этот момент в адаптере, но не нашел, где объясняется как правильно и почему. Подскажите пожалуйста. Вот код адаптера:

```
public class AddFilterAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddFilterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_filter_card);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.mcheckBox);

        }
    }

    public AddFilterAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public AddFilterAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.add_filter_card, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: ячейки переиспользуются при переиспользовании нужно сохранять и восстанавливаться состояние, эта проблема решена в библиотеке [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter), смотрите раздел [ViewState](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/wiki/Quick-start-with-ViewState)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Дело в том, что айтемы переиспользуются и для корректной работы нужно принудительно сохранять изменения в чекбоксах в отдельное хранилище, а при выводе востанавливать значения из него.

Kласс `RecyclerView` не реализует никаких готовых методов для работы с чекбоксами, поэтому все нужно писать самому.
Возможный вариант - завести отдельный массив булевых переменных и сохранять в него текущие состояния чекбоксов. На чекбоксы повешать слушатели, чтобы контролировать изменения состояний. При выводе в адаптере восстанавливать сохраненное ранее состояние.

```
public class AddFilterAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddFilterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    boolean[] checked;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_filter_card);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.mcheckBox);

        }
    }

    public AddFilterAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
        checked = new boolean[mDataset.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public AddFilterAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.add_filter_card, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               checked[position] = !checked[position];
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean[] getChecked(){
        return checked;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

метод `getChecked()` вернет полученные значения из адаптера "наружу", например в активити, где эти данные можно обработать:

```
// код в активити для получения чекнутых значений.
boolean[] checked = filterAdapter.getChecked();
```

Так же вы можете не заводить отдельный массив, а создать дополнительное поле в своей модели данных и писать сохранение состояния туда, так же оттуда и восстанавливать текущее состояние для вывода. Соответственно и возвращать через геттер коллекцию самих моделей. Это может быть полезно, когда требуется связать данные самой модели и их признак чекнутости.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я примерно такую же реализацию сделал после прочтения статьи со стартандроид, которую вы рекомендовали ранее. Однако, С Вашим кодом(как и с моим) чек боксы всё равно не правильно отображаются. Они продолжают появляться и исчезать при прокрутке. Возможно это из-за того, что у меня нет класса "модели данных", честно говоря, я не особо понимаю надобность в этом дополнительном классе. Ведь Адаптер заполняет список из какой-либо коллекции/массива. Или проблема не в этом?

Comment: проблема не в наличии либо отсутствии модели, это всего лишь одна из форм представления данных. Код в моем ответе должен работать корректно, попробуйте максимально точно воспроизвести его в своем проекте. У меня сейчас нет возможности проверить, если не решите проблему, завтра я протестирую его, попробуем разобраться.

Comment: Студия выделяет - "int position" в объявлении метода onBindViewHolder и ругается RecyclerView will not call on BindViewHolder again when the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item iself is invalited or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method, and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item latter(e.g. in a clicklistner) use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adaprer position.

Comment: Похоже говорится, что список не будет вызывать метод onBindViewHolder при отметке/снятии отметок в чек-боксах, поэтому нужно проверять по-другому.

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, что значение position не всегда будет корректным в случае сохранения его копии, для более надежного определения позиции рекомендуется использовать метод `getAdapterPosition()` класса `ViewHolder` - на это можно, в принципе не обращать внимания и это не должно являться причиной странного поведения, но исправил код  на всякий случай (объявление самого аргумента колбэка возвращающего позицию  `final`, вместо создания копии переменной, раз так не нравится). `final` нужно указывать, так как значение требуется в анонимном классе, а он принимает только константы.

Comment: При скролинге вниз, отмеченные чек-боксы всё равно отменяются..

Comment: @DenisMolodec Исправил код, заменил `OnCheckedChangeListener` на `OnClickListener` и соответственно логика сохранения состояния немного поменялась. Почему в первом варианте не работало мне лень разбираться, но теперь все работает.

Comment: Теперь работает. Благодарю за ответ! Подскажите что можно почитать, чтобы разобраться в этой теме, какой-нибудь подробный туториал можно и на англ, но желательно на русском

Comment: @DenisMolodec В какой именно теме? Я всем советую для начала читать книгу Б.Харди, на мой взгляд это самое толковое издание по разработке под андроид. Как раз недавно вышло второе издание на русском и [уже доступно на халяву](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=48070940), но лучше купить. Еще в своем блоге [Antonio Leiva](http://antonioleiva.com/) много интересного пишет, ну и еженедельные дайжесты [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net/#latest-issue) конечно. Вообще у меня в RSS ленте около 50 подписок по андроид, то там что прочитаешь, то в другом месте :)

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кто будет искать. Я накидал небольшой проектик, содержащий реализацию RecyclerView с чекбоксами. Бонусом идёт DiffUtill и базовые анимации.

https://github.com/FirstSpectr/RecyclerWithEdit