# В айтемах RecyclerView теряется ссылка на цвет лайка\дизлайка

Tags: java, android

Есть `RecyclerView`, находящийся во фрагменте. Он имеет количество лайков и кнопки нажатия лайков.

Проблема - при скролле вниз, цвета начинают прыгать по рандомным пальцам всех итемов списка, при повороте экрана все цвета вовсе сбрасываются.Сохранение информации при повороте экрана происходит за счет `setRetainInstance()`

Если нажать на палец вверх - он должен засветиться зеленым, противоположный палец вниз обязан стать серым, то же самое работает и в обратном порядке, нажимаешь дизлайк, палец вниз краснеет, палец вверх становится серым.

Я понимаю, что это далеко не самое лучшее решение, но опыта в таких вещах пока не очень много, было бы замечательно, если примерно приведете best practice к подобной ситуации, что-бы в будущем не писал такой зависимый код.

По идее хотел реализовать колбек, но по факту получилось нечто другое, но работающее.

```
public class LikesBtnClick implements View.OnClickListener, ThumbsListener {

private Word word;
private TextView likesView;
private ImageButton like;
private ThumbsListener subscriber;

private ThumbsListener getSubscriber() {
    return subscriber;
}

public void setSubscriber(ThumbsListener value) {
    subscriber = value;
}

public LikesBtnClick(Word word, TextView likesView, ImageButton like) {
    setWord(word);
    setLikesView(likesView);
    setLike(like);
    setSubscriber(subscriber);
}

public void setLikesView(TextView likesView) {
    this.likesView = likesView;
}

public void setWord(Word word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public void setLike(ImageButton like) {
    this.like = like;
}
public TextView getLikesView() {
    return likesView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Test", "сабскрайбер сработал");
    word.setLikes(word.getLikes() + 1);

    getLikesView().setText(Integer.toString(word.getLikes()));
    getSubscriber().callback(like);
}


@Override
public void callback(ImageButton dislike) {
    Log.d("Test","callback сработал");
    dislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumb_red_down);
    like.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbupgrey);
}
```

Класс обрабатывающий дизлайк

```
class DislikesBtnClick implements View.OnClickListener, ThumbsListener {
private ImageButton dislike;
private Word word;
private TextView likesView;
private ThumbsListener subscriber;
private LikesBtnClick likesBtnClick;
private ThumbsListener getSubscriber() {
    return subscriber;
}

public void setSubscriber(ThumbsListener value) {
    subscriber = value;
}


public TextView getLikesView() {
    return likesView;
}

public void setDislikesView(TextView likesView) {
    this.likesView = likesView;
}

public Word getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setDislike(ImageButton like){
    this.dislike = like;
}

public void setWord(Word word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public DislikesBtnClick(Word word, TextView likesView, ImageButton like) {
    setWord(word);
    setDislikesView(likesView);
    setDislike(like);
    setSubscriber(subscriber);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    word.setLikes(word.getLikes() - 1);
    getLikesView().setText(Integer.toString(word.getLikes()));
    getSubscriber().callback(dislike);
}


@Override
public void callback(ImageButton like) {
    like.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumb_up_green);
    dislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbdowngrey);

}
```

Класс фрагмента:

```
public class RecycleFragment extends Fragment {
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_recycle;
private View view;
private RecyclerView rvContacts;
private RvWordsAdapter adapter;
private List<Word> words;
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
private Context context;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initRecyclerView(view, context, this.behavior);



public static RecycleFragment getInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    RecycleFragment recycleFragment = new RecycleFragment();
    recycleFragment.setArguments(args);

    return recycleFragment;
}

public void setBehaviorSheet(BottomSheetBehavior behavior, FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    this.behavior = behavior;
    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior setBehaviorSheet" + behavior.getState());
}

private List<Word> getWords() {
    if (words == null) {
        return createMock();
    }
    return words;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    behavior = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getBehavior();
    frameLayout = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFrameSheet();



    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            subheader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    },5);

    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior onCreateView" + this.behavior);
    return view;
}

private void initRecyclerView(View view, Context context, BottomSheetBehavior behavior) {
    rvContacts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvWords);
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new RvWordsAdapter(getWords(), getActivity(), behavior, frameLayout);
    }
    rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);


    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

private List<Word> createMock() {
    List<Word> content = new ArrayList<>();
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Influence", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Might", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Capacity", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Potency", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Influence", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Might", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Capacity", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Potency", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Influence", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Might", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Capacity", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Potency", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Force", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Strength", 0));
    content.add(new Word("Energy", 0));
    return content;

}
```

Comment: В адаптере вам нужно сохранять состояния ваших айтемов (данных, которые в них находятся) для каждого айтема, в какое то отдельное хранилище, а при отображении по данной позиции - востанавливать, так как при создании списка их View-представления постоянно переиспользуются для экономии ресурсов и памяти, соответственно их содержимое и "скачет". По этому вопросу уже много ответов, в частности смотрите про `RecyclerView` с `Checkbox` - смысл точно тот же.

Comment: Смотрите, например [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я даже близко не представлял, в чем проблема и поэтому гуглить то, не знаю что получалось.
Теперь буду искать свое решение в этом направлении.