# Spinner в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-spinner

У меня есть `ListView`, в `Item` `ListView` есть выпадающий список (`Spinner`), так же есть кнопка "+" с помощью которой пользователь может добавлять новые `Items` в `ListView.` Допустим юзер, создал два `Items` и выбрал в них определенные значения в `Spinner`, при добавлении нового `Item`, значения выбранные в первых двух `Items` в `Spinner` сбиваются, не могу понять, как правильно сохранять значения и потом отображать их при создании новых `Items`.

Была идея сохранять в `ArrayList` при `onItemSelected` в массив выбранные значения, но тогда не понятно, что делать, если юзер выбрал сначала одно значение, а потом поменял его на другое. Или тут возможно нужно использовать `Expandable ListView`?

Код в Activity:

```
public class ClaimWorkActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList <String> workCount = new ArrayList<>();
WorksAdapter worksAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.claim_work_activity);
        workCount.add("1");
 lvListWork = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListWork);
        btnAdd =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        worksAdapter = new WorksAdapter(this);
        lvListWork.setAdapter(worksAdapter);

  btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    workCount.add("1");
                    worksAdapter.addall(workCount);
                }
            });
            worksAdapter.addall(workCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class WorksAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<String> objects;

    private String [] workType = {"Work type 1", "Work type 2", "Work type 3", "Work type 4", "Work type 5"};


    public WorksAdapter(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        objects=new ArrayList<>();
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void addall(ArrayList<String> object){
        objects.clear();
        objects.addAll(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_work_item, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWorkNumber)).setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
        //objects.get(position)
        Spinner spinnerClaimWorkName= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.tvClaimWorkName);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterWorkType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, workType);
        adapterWorkType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerClaimWorkName.setAdapter(adapterWorkType);
        spinnerClaimWorkName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Work Type", workType[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: В общем то алгоритм работы с изменяющими текущее состояние элементами айтема [один и тот же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345). В адаптере создаете служебный массив и сохраняете туда все изменения состояния виджета через его слушатель (в спиннере это номер выбранной позиции), при выводе в `getView()` принудительно устанавливаете состояния элементу из этого массива, в случае с `Spinner` - методом `setSelection(position)`. Потом этот массив можно забрать через геттер адаптера в активити или любом другом получателе, которому требуется информация по выбранным в списке элементам.

Comment: Так же смотрите [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8498183), здесь немного другой алгоритм

Comment: @pavlofff Ок, спасибо! Буду разбираться!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решила переделать  `ListView` со `Spinner`, в `ExpandableListView`, мне кажется, что в данной ситуации он лучше подходит, хотя бы потому нужно будет использовать всего один адаптер. Я установила `OnClickListener` на `ExpandableListView` и каждый раз когда юзер выбирает позицию `child`, я присваиваю это значение списку на основании которого строятся `headers` и обновляю весь `ExpandableListView`. Так же у меня есть кнопка `btnAdd` с помощью которой юзер может добавлять новые Items, добавляется новый элемент в массив на основания которого строятся headers и обновляется `ExpandableListView`.

Код Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
ClaimExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
private Button btnAdd;
List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    List<String> docTypes;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.claim_work_activity);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvMain);
        btnAdd =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

prepareListData();
            listAdapter = new ClaimExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                    listDataHeader.set(groupPosition, listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition));
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), docTypes);
                    listAdapter.updateData(listDataHeader,listDataChild);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listDataHeader.add("Выберите тип работ");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(listDataHeader.size()-1), docTypes);
                    listAdapter.updateData(listDataHeader,listDataChild);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Выберите тип работ");

        // Adding child data
        docTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        docTypes.add("Work Type 1");
        docTypes.add("Work Type 2");
        docTypes.add("Work Type 3");
        docTypes.add("Work Type 4");
        docTypes.add("Work Type 5");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), docTypes); 
    }
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class ClaimExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    public List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ClaimExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                      HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    public ClaimExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_explist_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list_group, null);
        }

        TextView tvWorkNumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvWorkNumber);
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvClaimWorkName);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        int displayPosition=groupPosition+1;
        tvWorkNumber.setText(String.valueOf(displayPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public void updateData(List<String> groups,
                           HashMap<String, List<String>> children) {
        this._listDataHeader = groups;
        this._listDataChild = children;
    }
}
```