# Как из активити получить доступ к view элементу, который находится во ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, viewholder

В главной активити есть метод воспроизведения аудио в одиночном и поочередном порядке:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_content);

    SQLiteOpenHelperDataLessonsContents lessonsContents = new SQLiteOpenHelperDataLessonsContents(this);
    lessonsContent = lessonsContents.getLessonsContent(forContentLessons);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvLessonContent.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapterContentsLessons = new AdapterContentsLessons(lessonsContent);
    rvLessonContent.setAdapter(adapterContentsLessons);
}

private void playAllAudio() {
    play();

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (currentIndex < lessonsContent.size() - 1) {
                currentIndex++;
                play();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            } else {
                tbPlayAllAudio.setChecked(false);
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void play() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    rvLessonContent.smoothScrollToPosition(currentIndex);
    // Здесь я хочу задавать цвет для айтема в ресайкле
    adapterContentsLessons.notifyDataSetChanged();

    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(
            lessonsContent.get(currentIndex).getLessonsNameAudio(),
            "raw", "com.example");

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class AdapterContentsLessons extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderContentsLessons> {

private final List<ModelContentsLessons> mContentInChapters;

public AdapterContentsLessons(List<ModelContentsLessons> contentInChapters) {
    this.mContentInChapters = contentInChapters;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderContentsLessons onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.content_lesson_item, parent, false);

    return new HolderContentsLessons(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HolderContentsLessons holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    final String strContentRussian = mContentInChapters.get(position).getLessonsContentRussian();
    //final String strLessonAudioFileName = mContentInChapters.get(position).getLessonsNameAudio();

    holder.tvLessonsContentRussian.setText(Html.fromHtml(strContentRussian));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContentInChapters.size();
}
}
```

Код viewHolder:

```
public class HolderContentsLessons extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public final CardView cvContentLesson;
public final TextView tvLessonsContentRussian;

public HolderContentsLessons(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    cvContentLesson = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_content_lesson);
    tvLessonsContentRussian = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lessons_content_russian);
}
}
```

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы в методе `playAllAudio` я мог получить доступ к `CardView` из `ViewHolder` и задать ему цвет.

Comment: Оно конечно можно, если Вы понимаете, что вью в `RecyclerView` переиспользуются и когда Вы прокрутите эту карточку за пределы области видимости она вылезет как следующая - с тем же цветом, но новыми данными.

Comment: @woesss я понимаю, я объявил в активити переменную emptyIndex присвоил ей значение -1, затем получил текущую позицию позиции ресайкла в `currentIndex`, затем в определенном методе сделал `emptyIndex = currentIndex` вызвал `notifyDataSetChanged()`и сделал условие, если `emptyIndex == currentIndex` то нужно перекрасить айтем в один цвет, если не равен то в другой, все работает как надо, но я застрял на том, что не могу получить доступ из активити к кард вью.

Comment: К сожалению нравы некоторых участников оставляют желать лучшего, вместо минусов и голосования за закрытие можно элементарно объяснить, что в моем вопросе не так, я не животное, а человек, и способен понять и принять и если мне объяснят в чем тупость моего вопроса, я его удалю или переформулирую.

Comment: вам не нужен такой сложный алгоритм, как вы описали. вам нужно сделать простой сеттер в адаптер, который будет заносить в внутрений массив адаптера флаг, что айтем по позиции должен быть другого цвета и все. при биндинге на айтем по этому флагу выставлять цвет айтема.

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345), там алгоритм сохранения состояния чекбоксов, но принцип такой же. Если добавите в вопрос код адаптера, смогу в ответе написать алгоритм по вашему примеру.

Comment: @pavlofff Переформулировал вопрос. Вся загвоздка в том, что я в главной активити получаю длину массива ресайкла и по нажатию на кнопку плей воспроизвожу весь массив от 0 и до конца массива, и так как все это происходит в активи, а не в адаптере, я застрял на том, что не могу из активити задавать цвет пункту ресайкла

Comment: задать цвет - это два варианта цвета (дефолтный для айтемов или выделенный атем) или произвольный цвет (каждый айтем может иметь свой, отличный от других цвет)?

Comment: @pavlofff Да, основной и выделенный, чтобы получилось так, когда идет вопроизведение, текущий айтем перекрашивается в цвет который я задам, а как пойдет следующий, предыдущий становится белым, а новый перекрашивается и таким образом юзер понимает какой именно айтем на данный момент вопроизведен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вам нужно выделять только один элемент из всего списка, то алгоритм будет совсем простой. В адаптер передается позиция, которая должна быть выделена, прошлая позиция сбрасывается.

```
public class AdapterContentsLessons extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderContentsLessons> {

private final List<ModelContentsLessons> mContentInChapters;
private int currentPosition = -1; // текущая выделенная позиция, -1 - ничего не выделено.

public AdapterContentsLessons(List<ModelContentsLessons> contentInChapters) {
    this.mContentInChapters = contentInChapters;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderContentsLessons onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.content_lesson_item, parent, false);

    return new HolderContentsLessons(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HolderContentsLessons holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    final String strContentRussian = mContentInChapters.get(position).getLessonsContentRussian();
    //final String strLessonAudioFileName = mContentInChapters.get(position).getLessonsNameAudio();

    holder.tvLessonsContentRussian.setText(Html.fromHtml(strContentRussian));
    // устанавливаем значение цвета для айтема
    holder.cvContentLesson.setBackgroundColor((position == currentPosition)?  0xFFAAAAAA: 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

// метод, устанавливающий цвет на айтем
public void setItemSelected(int position){
    int tmp = currentPosition;
    currentPosition = position;
    if (tmp != -1) notifyItemChanged(tmp); // восстанавливаем цвет ранее выделенного
    if (position != -1) notifyItemChanged(position); // выделяем новый
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContentInChapters.size();
}
}
```

здесь: *0xFFFFFFFF* - основной цвет айтемов, *0xFFAAAAAA* - цвет выделения. Вы можете установить свои значения.

Теперь, чтобы выделить какой то айтем в списке, вы вызываете в активити метод адаптера:

```
adapterContentsLessons.setItemSelected(currentIndex);
```

чтобы снять выделение со всех айтемов:

```
adapterContentsLessons.setItemSelected(-1);
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, что было нужно. Вы просто гигант программирования))

Comment: на самом деле моя заслуга тут не велика, это шаблонный код выделения айтема в списке :) Немного исправил метод выделения айтема, чтобы не "падал" при значении -1