# Как заполнить массив числами long которые получаются при выборе checkBox?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть список и каждый элемент списка имеет свой checkBox. Я хочу заполнить массив id элементов у которых был выбран checkBox. Вот слушатель выбора:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            int k = message.getId();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                final long[] number = new long[messageList.size()];
                number[i] = messageList.get(k);;
                Toast.makeText(ctx, Arrays.toString(number), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Вот например у меня есть список из трех элементов и если например 2 из 3 элементов были выбраны, то я получаю такой массив - `[0, 2_id,3_id]`. Я не могу понять как это сделать. Вроде погуглил сделал что-то типа закидывания элемента, но в итоге получил такой результат: например у нас есть id второго элемента, и добавление у меня работало так - `[id,0,0]->[0,id,0]->[0,0,id]`. Что-то походу сделал не так, но не могу понять что именно.

Comment: Вы же в цикле массив каждый раз заново создаете.

Comment: та это я уже заметил))) вынес массив из цикла, но теперь все элементы массива равны одному

Comment: Цикл вообще не нужен. Массив - в поле класса, в методе вписываем один `id` в **одну** позицию.

Comment: Честно говоря, плохо понимаю как прописать один id  в одну позицию, думал что в цикле можно будет как то прописать, но теперь вообще не получается

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, цикл вам нужен чтобы наполнить массив данными на момент вывода checkbox! Я бы повесил на checkbox onClick - и обрабатывал нажатия, с обновлением данных в адаптере (recyclerView же?). Нажали на чекбокс - проверили данные в массиве, поменяли значение, обновили.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, посмотрите для начала как вообще делается адаптер с чекбоксами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/11515. Потому что Вы тоже столкнётесь с проблемой из того вопроса, с нынешним подходом

Comment: @woesss, я ознакомился с предложенным вопросом, там в принципи все описывается и решает вроде как мою задачу, но у меня так и не получилось довести адаптер до нужного состояния, почему-то не принимается строка `checked[position] = !checked[position];` не знаете в чем может быть проблема, если все почти сделать так как в том вопросе что вы мне скинули?

Comment: Тип массива `checked` у Вас `boolean[]`? Отрицание (`!`) к другим типам не применимо.

Comment: нет не `boolean[]` я забрал эту строку, но теперь вообще ничего не выбирается, пробовал закинуть в слушатель выбора `checked [messageList.size()] = message.getId();` но приложение вылетает с криком что массив не вошел в свои пределы) что-то вообще теперь ничего не понятно

Comment: Я бы лучше добавил булево поле в класс сообщения - его менял по клику на чекбокс, по нему же выставлял галку в `onBindViewHolder`, а когда нужно получить все выбранные - пробежался по списку сообщений циклом, проверяя это поле.

Comment: `messageList.size()` - всегда больше любого индекса в списке. Нужно использовать позицию элемента, по которому кликнули: `checked [holder.getAdapterPosition()] = message.getId();`