# Не получается получить доступ к функции другого класса

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть уже несколько вопросов связанных с этой задачей, вот например этот [Как заполнить массив числами long которые получаются при выборе checkBox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889359/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-long-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-checkbox). Там мне предоставили вопрос с ответом который решил мою проблему, но все-равно есть некоторые сложности в решении моей проблемы. Суть проста, выделить несколько элементов списка, в моем случае это сообщения, и удалить их, или переслать. Все вроде просто, но как всегда возникли сложности. В адаптере списка получаю массив состоящий из id выделенных сообщений, но теперь непонятно как получать этот массив в другом классе. Изначально вообще непонятно как сделать само удаление. Вопрос не по отправке на сервер запроса, а вообще про логику поведения программы - вот выделили мы например 2 сообщения, дальше я думаю сделать видимой кнопку которая будет удалять эти сообщения, но проблема в том что я получаю массив с идентификаторами в адаптере списка, а удалять придется в главном классе, а для этого нужно каким-то образом вытащить из адаптера массив. Вот есть в адаптере функция:

```
public int[] getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
```

которая возвращает массив моих чисел, но я столкнулся с проблемой, когда главный класс не видит этот метод. Вот весь адаптер целиком:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SenderHolder> {

    private Integer type;
    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    public int[] checked;
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id";
    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";
    private static final String keyDraftMessageId = "draft_message_id";

    ListAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messageList, Context ctx, int type) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.type = type;
        checked = new int[messageList.size()];
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        boolean attachment = message.isAttachment();
        Integer new_one = message.getNewField();


        if (attachment) {
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
        }

        if (new_one == 1 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getSender_name())) {
            holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());


        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                switch (type) {
                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyDraftMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                }

                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (message.isCan_delete()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //holder.deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {

                            checked[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = message.getId();
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, Arrays.toString(checked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public int[] getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;
        final ImageView attachIV;
        final CheckBox checkBox;
        final Button deleteBtn;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            attachIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clip);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_item);
            deleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }
}
```

и теперь мне нужно как-то вытащить отсюда массив, студия предлагает сделать этот метод статичным, чтобы все работало, но тогда метод вообще не может ничего вернуть нормально. В чем может быть проблема при вызове этого метода?

### UPDATE

я кажется смог наконец-то сформулировать проблему для себя и соответственно мне проще у всех спросить то что нужно. У меня есть метод в адаптере который возвращает массив выделенных для удаления элементов списка, и мне нужно получить в главном классе этот массив. Для того чтобы нормально вызывался метод, мне студия предложила сделать этот метод в статическим. Логика в том что я хочу при нажатии на кнопку удалять выделенные элементы списка, в моем случае это сообщения. То есть соответственно мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку получить этот массив и послать запрос на сервер. Честно говоря у меня почему-то не получается добавить пока кнопку на экран со списком, но суть я думаю стала ясна. Если все-таки нужен какой-то код то я докину слушатель нажатий на кнопку.

Comment: Публичные методы видны всегда. Если у вас не видно - значит вы не тот класс импортировали.

Comment: Проблема не в методе, а в том как Вы его вызываете.  
По имени класса (`ListAdapter.getChecked()`) вызываются статические методы, а экземплярные через ссылку на экземпляр адаптера. Код адаптера в этом вопросе нам не интересен - покажите код "главного", если не разберётесь.

Comment: вопрос не по моему вопросу, если я например не сегодня добавлю код а например завтра, или вообще в пн, то вы это обновление увидите?

Comment: Если лично я, то нет - участник получает уведомление при любых действиях в его вопросе, при комментировании его ответа и при прямом обращении к нему через `@user_name`. Но обновлённый вопрос поднимается в списке на вкладке "Недавно Обновлённые" и его заметят те, кто эту вкладку просматривают.

Comment: @woesss я обновил вопрос, надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Comment: В Вашем апдейте ничего нового - в контексте вопроса не имеет значения что Вы собираетесь с этим массивом делать. Важно **как** Вы обращаетесь к адаптеру, вызывая этот метод. Я бы посоветовал Вам освежить знания и разобраться раз и на всегда что есть класс и его члены, а что есть экземпляр (объект) и его члены и в чём между ними разница.

Comment: @woesss, вроде как получилось вызвать метод который отвечает за массив, но он почему-то показывает все 0, вероятнее всего причиной этого есть недостаток моих знаний))

Comment: При создании массива он автоматом заполняется нулями (должно же что-то быть в ячейках). Когда ставится отметка - Вы меняете нуль на `id` в соответствующей позиции. Итого: весь массив забит нулями, кроме чекнутых позиций. Если Вам хочется, чтобы там были только `id` - замените массив на коллекцию, например `HashSet`: когда чекнули - добавляем (`add`), сняли галку - удаляем (`remove`).

Comment: Там же где Вы заносили `id` в массив

Comment: а как лучше обновить этот вопрос еще раз, или создавать новый с тем что я делаю? потому-что вроде как получается добавлять, но не пойму как дальше получить доступ к выбранным чекбоксам, вроде добавляется нормально, но дальше не могу пройти