# Как обратиться к айтему списка GridAdapter вне его метода, зная его позицию?

Tags: java, android, adapter, grid, viewholder

Не могу получить нужный мне элемент из ViewHolder'a по позиции, и применить для него некие изменения (заменить background).

Собственно сам класс адаптера:

```
public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements IShowAdListener {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    ArrayList<soundList> soundlist = new ArrayList<soundList>();
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PerfectMediaPlayer[] mediaPlayer;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static GridAdapter adap;
    SoundDB sdb;
    public static MainActivity av;
    AppCompatActivity compatActivity;
    public int posi;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceID, ArrayList<String> str, ArrayList<soundList> soundlist, ViewPager viewPager, SoundDB sdb) {
        super(context, textViewResourceID, str);
        this.soundlist = soundlist;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.str = str;
        adap = this;
        mediaPlayer = new PerfectMediaPlayer[soundlist.size()];
        this.sdb = sdb;
    }

    public void update() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_lay, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itext);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iimg);
            viewHolder.seekBar1 = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            viewHolder.hot_bg = (RoundedImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hot_bg);
            viewHolder.hot_img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hot_img);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        LinearLayout fr = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fr);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_gradient);

        viewHolder.title.setText(soundlist.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(soundlist.get(position).getIcon());
        int isactive = 0;
        int seekvalue = 0;
        viewHolder.seekBar1.setProgress(soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic());

        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.allmedia.size(); i++) {
            int ptype = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusictype();
            int pid = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusicid();
            int id = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getId();
            String ppath = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getFile_path();
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 11) {
                if ((ptype == soundlist.get(position).getMusictype()) && (pid == soundlist.get(position).getMusicid())) {
                    isactive = 1;
                    seekvalue = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getAddMusic();
                    mediaPlayer[position] = MainActivity.allmedia.get(i);
                    str.set(position, "pus");
                }
            } else {
                if (id == soundlist.get(position).getId()) {
                    isactive = 1;
                    seekvalue = MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getAddMusic();
                    mediaPlayer[position] = MainActivity.allmedia.get(i);
                    str.set(position, "pus");
                }

            }
        }
        if (isactive == 1) {
            viewHolder.seekBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);
            viewHolder.seekBar1.setProgress(seekvalue);
        }

        fr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
                LinearLayout fr1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fr);
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_gradient);

                if (seekBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {

                        if (MainActivity.allmedia.size() < 8) {

                            if (mediaPlayer[position] == null) {
                                soundlist.get(position).setAddMusic(seekBar.getProgress());
                                mediaPlayer[position] = PerfectMediaPlayer.create(getContext(), soundlist.get(position).getMusicid());
                                mediaPlayer[position].setVolume(soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic(), soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic());
                                MainActivity.allmedia.add(mediaPlayer[position]);
                                MainActivity.mediaindex.add(soundlist.get(position));
                                seekBar.setProgress(soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic());
                            }

                            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);
                            MainActivity.notification_on_off = 1;
                            SoundsActivity.nplay_count = 0;

                            if (mediaPlayer[position] != null)
                                mediaPlayer[position].start();

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_shadow);
                        if (mediaPlayer[position] != null) {
                            mediaPlayer[position].stop();
                            mediaPlayer[position].release();
                            mediaPlayer[position] = null;
                            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.mediaindex.size(); i++) {
                                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 9) {
                                    if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusicid() == soundlist.get(position).getMusicid()) {
                                        if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusictype() == soundlist.get(position).getMusictype())
                                            MainActivity.mediaindex.remove(i);
                                        MainActivity.allmedia.remove(i);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getFile_path() == soundlist.get(position).getFile_path()) {
                                        if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusictype() == soundlist.get(position).getMusictype())
                                            MainActivity.mediaindex.remove(i);
                                        MainActivity.allmedia.remove(i);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });


        switch (soundlist.get(position).getTitle()) {
            case "1":
            case "2":
            case "3":
                viewHolder.hot_bg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.hot_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
                        LinearLayout fr1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fr);
                        ImageView view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_gradient);

                        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 12) {


                            if (position == (soundlist.size() - 1)) {
                                AddActivity.as = adap;
                                AddActivity.pos = position;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddActivity.class);
                                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                if (seekBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {

                                    if (MainActivity.allmedia.size() < 8) {

                                        if (mediaPlayer[position] == null) {
                                            soundlist.get(position).setAddMusic(seekBar.getProgress());
                                            mediaPlayer[position] = PerfectMediaPlayer.create(getContext(), soundlist.get(position).getFile_path());
                                            mediaPlayer[position].setVolume(soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic(), soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic());
                                            MainActivity.allmedia.add(mediaPlayer[position]);
                                            MainActivity.mediaindex.add(soundlist.get(position));
                                            seekBar.setProgress(soundlist.get(position).getAddMusic());
                                        }
                                        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);
                                        MainActivity.notification_on_off = 1;
                                        SoundsActivity.nplay_count = 0;

                                        if (mediaPlayer[position] != null)
                                            mediaPlayer[position].start();
                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_shadow);

                                    if (mediaPlayer[position] != null) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.allmedia.size(); i++) {

                                            if (mediaPlayer[position] == MainActivity.allmedia.get(i)) {
                                                mediaPlayer[position].stop();
                                                mediaPlayer[position].release();
                                                mediaPlayer[position] = null;
                                                MainActivity.mediaindex.remove(i);
                                                MainActivity.allmedia.remove(i);
                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (MainActivity.allmedia.size() == 0)
                                        thisA.stopNotification();

                                }

                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } else {

                            if (seekBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {

                                if (MainActivity.allmedia.size() < 8) {

                                    posi = position;

                                    btmDialog();

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            } else {

                                seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_shadow);
                                if (mediaPlayer[position] != null) {
                                    mediaPlayer[position].stop();
                                    mediaPlayer[position].release();
                                    mediaPlayer[position] = null;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.mediaindex.size(); i++) {
                                        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 9) {
                                            if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusicid() == soundlist.get(position).getMusicid()) {
                                                if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusictype() == soundlist.get(position).getMusictype())
                                                    MainActivity.mediaindex.remove(i);
                                                MainActivity.allmedia.remove(i);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getFile_path() == soundlist.get(position).getFile_path()) {
                                                if (MainActivity.mediaindex.get(i).getMusictype() == soundlist.get(position).getMusictype())
                                                    MainActivity.mediaindex.remove(i);
                                                MainActivity.allmedia.remove(i);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                });
                break;
        }

        return v;

    }


    private void btmDialog() {
        BottomDialog.create(thisA.getSupportFragmentManager())
                .setViewListener(new BottomDialog.ViewListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void bindView(View v) {
                        initView(v); // // You can do any of the necessary the operation with the view
                    }
                })
                .setLayoutRes(R.layout.dialog_layout)
                .setDimAmount(0.2f)            // Dialog window dim amount(can change window background color）, range：0 to 1，default is : 0.2f
                .setCancelOutside(true)     // click the external area whether is closed, default is : true
                .setTag("BottomDialog") // setting the DialogFragment tag
                .show();
    }

        @Override
        public void onFinished(String s, FinishState finishState) {
        if (finishState == FinishState.COMPLETED) {
            if (s.equals(Id)) {

                //Выполняем необходимые действия 
                if (mediaPlayer[posi] == null) {
                    soundlist.get(posi).setAddMusic(seekBar.getProgress());
                    mediaPlayer[posi] = PerfectMediaPlayer.create(getContext(), soundlist.get(posi).getMusicid());
                    mediaPlayer[posi].setVolume(soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic(), soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic());
                    MainActivity.allmedia.add(mediaPlayer[posi]);
                    MainActivity.mediaindex.add(soundlist.get(posi));
                    seekBar.setProgress(soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic());
                }

                seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.notification_on_off = 1;
                SoundsActivity.nplay_count = 0;

                if (mediaPlayer[posi] != null)
                    mediaPlayer[posi].start();

                 // Как поменять нужному itemView из ViewHolder'a по позиции какие либо данные?
                 // Здесь нужно применить строчку которая ниже
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);
                 // но как добраться до этого view по позиции?
            }
        }
    }

        private void initView(final View view) {

        final Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
        });
    }

       private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        SeekBar seekBar1;
        RoundedImageView hot_bg;
        ImageView hot_img;
    }
}
```

**В методе `onFinished()` нужно добраться до элемента "view" 
который определен в методе getView() :**

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            View v = convertView;
            ...
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_gradient);
            ...
}

            @Override
            public void onFinished(String s, FinishState finishState) {
            if (finishState == FinishState.COMPLETED) {
                if (s.equals(Id)) {

                    //Выполняем необходимые действия 
                    if (mediaPlayer[posi] == null) {
                        soundlist.get(posi).setAddMusic(seekBar.getProgress());
                        mediaPlayer[posi] = PerfectMediaPlayer.create(getContext(), soundlist.get(posi).getMusicid());
                        mediaPlayer[posi].setVolume(soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic(), soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic());
                        MainActivity.allmedia.add(mediaPlayer[posi]);
                        MainActivity.mediaindex.add(soundlist.get(posi));
                        seekBar.setProgress(soundlist.get(posi).getAddMusic());
                    }

                    seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.notification_on_off = 1;
                    SoundsActivity.nplay_count = 0;

                    if (mediaPlayer[posi] != null)
                        mediaPlayer[posi].start();

                     // Как поменять нужному itemView из ViewHolder'a по позиции какие либо данные?
                     // Здесь нужно применить строчку которая ниже
                     view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);
                     // но как добраться до этого view по позиции?
                }
            }
        }
```

**p.s:** определять view не из метода getView, а в самом классе адаптера?
А как применить `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_pink);` к определенному элементу списка ViewHolder'a?

Comment: Много лишнего кода, много лишних букаф. Обычно во вьюхолдере рециклера используется `getAdapterPosition()`, попробуйте

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Как мне с помощью него вне адаптера заменить бекграунд у айтема определенного?

Comment: Так делать не следует - если позиция не видна на экране, то она не связана ни с каким вью и соответственно изменить бэкграунд не получится. Почитайте ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/11515 - там про чекбоксы, но смысл тот же. Из вне Вы будете изменять не вью, а "состояние" и просить адаптер обновить вью (`notifyItemSetChanged(...)`)

Comment: @woesss, да мне нужно просто "перезагрузить" "обновить" адаптер, а точнее его содержимое. Не обязательно менять бекграунд строго находя айтем по позиции. Потому что бекграунд у айтема нужного меняется как надо, если я соседний айтем тапну, либо пролистну Табы с фрагментами и вернусь обратно. Мне нужно что то наподобие ``.recreate();`` метода, который в активностях применяется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился перезагрузкой ViewPager'a из главной активности, и повторной установкой адаптера. По моему мнению, это не самое лучшее решение и выход из данной ситуации.

Добавил в классе GridAdapter'а в нужном для меня методе вызов `MainActivity.set_viewp();`

Собственно сам метод в главной активности:

```
    public void set_viewp() {

        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        viewPager = ViewFindUtils.find(decorView, R.id.pager);
        activity = this;

        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ...
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout = ViewFindUtils.find(decorView, R.id.tl);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        initToolbar();   
    }
```