# sharedpreferences recyclerview сохранение состояния checkbox

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-shared-preferences

Подскажите у меня есть recycler view и на нем флажки .Вопрос:как сделать так чтобы когда флажок.isChecked() то он запоминает с помощью sharedpreferences  что именно этот флажок исчекид и при повторном запуске приложения recycler View воспроизводил 
все флажки с учетом sharedpreferences.Сам пробовал не смог.Короче мне нужно чтобы sharedpreferences сохранял состояние checkBox и при запуске приложения воспроизводил состояния (sharedpreferences )checkBox
вот код  адаптера

```
public  class Adapter_class2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_class2.ViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater1;
private List<ModelClass2> modelClass2;

Adapter_class2(Context context, List<ModelClass2> modelClass) {
    this.modelClass2 = modelClass;
    this.inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public Adapter_class2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_layout2, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter_class2.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ModelClass2 model_class = modelClass2.get(i);

    viewHolder.imageView_ex.setImageResource(model_class.getImage_resourse());
  viewHolder.kol_times.setText(model_class.getText_for_times());
  viewHolder.name_exercise.setText(model_class.getText_for_ex());
  if(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
      switch (i){
          case 1:break;//для первого checkBox
          case 2:break;//для второго checkBox
          case 3:break;//для третьего checkBox
          case 4:break;//для четвертого checkBox
          case 5:break;//для пятго  checkBox
          case 6:break;//для шестого checkBox
          case 7:break;//и т.д
          case 8:break;
          case 9:break;
          case 10:break;
          case 11:break;
          case 12:break;
          case 13:break;
          case 14:break;
          case 15:break;
          case 16:break;
          case 17:break;
          case 18:break;



      }
  }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClass2.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final TextView name_exercise;
    final TextView kol_times;
    final ImageView imageView_ex;
    final CheckBox checkBox;
    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name_exercise=view.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        kol_times=view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        imageView_ex=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        checkBox =view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Лучше сохраняйте состояния ваших объектов в sqlite базу

Comment: преференсы самое неудачное место для хранения состояния чекбоксов списков, так как они хранят только пары ключ-значение, а списки - это массивы данных/ Вторее крайне неудачное решение - использовать switch-case для определения какой чекбокс обрабатывать, это даже костылем нельзя назвать. Можете взять за основу [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345) и при закрытии активити сохранять куда то (есть простые библиотеки [вроде этой](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper)) массив состояния чекбоксов, при старте восстанавливать оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй для каждого:

```
    switch(viewHolder.checkBox.getId()) {
case R.id.checkBox:
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
        .putBoolean("checkBox1", checked).commit();
    break;
}
```

И где инициализируешь свой checkbox добавь:

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
boolean checked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getBoolean("checkBox1", false);
checkBox1.setChecked(checked);
```

Comment: а почему не мой способ switch

Comment: В твоем switch ты перебираешь модельные классы, а не checkbox, хотя ты написал, что у тебя в одном item несколько checkox, если тебе нужно для своих item с одним chexbox - отставь свой

Comment: не совсем понял что означает  checked

Comment: преференсы вообще не предназначены для решения такой задачи и от них надо отказаться .а не костылить что то

Comment: @pavlofff почему

Comment: @pavlofff и что тогда использовать