# Какие значения фиксированы для объекта RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть двухуровневый RecyclerView, обозначающий конкретную папку и файл. У этих объектов на gui есть галочка(checkbox) и мне нужно сохранять состояние этой галочки. Через что можно реализовать? (костыли приветствуются)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог это реализовать! Создал массив объектов, в который добавлял/убирал выбранные элементы. Для синхронизации с родителем я каждому объекту присваивал ViewHolder каждый раз, когда он появляется на экране(onBindViewHolder). Так же, в RecyclerViewAdapter есть свойство hasStableIds, которое позволяет закрепить цифровые id за каждым элементом(как я понял). Но у меня были папки с файлами, поэтому я использовал первый вариант(List).
В модель родителя и ребенка я добавил св-ва curholder и path.