# Не понимаю как пройти по всем checkbox'ам в recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

Собираюсь проходить по всем checkbox'ам, которые находятся в recyclerview для того чтобы проверять их на то выбран он или нет.

Пытаюсь обращаться к checkbox таким образом:

```
val element = recyclerview.getChildAt(i).checkbox as CheckBox.
```

Он впринципе работает, но когда recyclerView содержит много элементов, что они выходят за пределы экрана, то он просто не видит остальные элементы.

Прохожу по recyclerview таким способом:

```
for(i: Int in 0 until recyclerview.size)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345

Answer (score 3):

Вы не сможете пройти RecyclerView по его всем элементам т.к. RecyclerView реализует паттерн ViewHolder. Суть паттерна в том, чтоб в каждый момент времени хранить в себе тольк те View которые видны пользователю и парочку соседних. А значит хранить в себе их он не может.

Вашу проблему можно решить следующим способом:

- Создаете модель для вашего RecyclerView которая будет в себе хранить данные, нужные для вашего заполнения вашего item-а и флаг `isChecked`:

  ```
  class ListItem(

      val data: SomeObject, 

      var isChecked: Boolean
  )
  ```
- Внутри вашего RecyclerView вы храните список этих моделей. При каждом изменении вашего CheckBox-a вы изменяете в вашем списке флаг `isChecked` по нужной позиции.
- Далее все что вам нужно - это пройтись по этому списку и проверить ваши CheckBox-ы. Если это снаружи адаптера - напишите свой метод для получения этого списка.